# D3 v3 appending checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

Am working with collapsible tree top to bottom orientatin. Here i stuck with some problem.
To implement the tree am using d3.v3.js. How can i append check box into the tree for each node.

```
    // Create the link lines.
    svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(links)
      .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .attr("d", d3.svg.diagonal().projection(function(d) { return [o.x(d)+15, o.y(d)]; }));

        svg.selectAll("input")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter().append("foreignObject")
        .attr('x' , o.x)
        .attr('y',  o.y)
        .attr('width', 50)
        .attr('height', 20)
        .append("xhtml:body")
        .html("<form><input type=checkbox id=check></input></form>")
     .on("click", function(d, i){
            console.log(svg.select("#check").node().checked) 
            }) ;

    svg.selectAll("image")
        .data(nodes)
     .enter().append("image")
        .attr('x' , o.x)
        .attr('y',  o.y)
        .attr('width', 30)
        .attr('height', 20)
        .attr("xlink:href", "check.png")
  }); 
});
```

Checkbox in appending in to svg but not been visible in browser. Anybody please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 3):

You need to be creating a holder for the foreignObjects (i.e. checkbox's) and not the inputs in this line:

```
svg.selectAll("input")
```

which should be

```
svg.selectAll("foreignObject")
```

you then need to drive the number of checkbox's with the data as in, `data(data)` and bind it with the `enter()`, as you've done.  If you want multiple elements to appear you need to use dynamic variable for the x and y.  In a simple example that would be `.attr('x', function (d,i) { return d.x; })`. So putting it all together in a fiddle you get [this](http://fiddle.jshell.net/TExct/).

Comment: Am using d3.v3.js is the js is ok for this

Comment: The fiddle used version 3.0.4 and I tested it with the version on the d3 site, so it should be OK!

Answer (score 1):

Your checkbox does not appear because you cannot append arbitrary html elements to svg. You should use either < g > or floating elements:

```
#canvas {
  position: relative;
}
```

Then append checkbox element using:

```
d3.select("#canvas")
  .append("input")
  .attr("type", "checkbox")
  .style("position", "absolute")
  .style("top", "320")
  .style("left", "150")
```

Comment: Am looking to append check box for every point that related with the image.User can able to select perticular image by clicking the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is more usefull those are using **Bootstrap**.To append checkbox in bootstrap we need to specify **label** and **span** expectly while appending foreign object. Otherwise it not be visible in browser

```
 svg.selectAll("foreignObject")
   .data(nodes).enter()
   .append("foreignObject")
   .attr('x', o.x)
   .attr('y',  o.y)
   .attr('width', 30)
   .attr('height', 20)
   .append("xhtml:tree")
   .html("<label class='inline'><input type='checkbox'><span class='lbl'> </span>               </label>");
```