# Adding foreign element to d3,js now showing

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I am trying to add checkboxes and text in a node. See below image of what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

I can see the checkbox in elements view but cannot view it in page.

[image]

But this is what I am getting for now.

[image]

Below is the code used.

```
(function() {
        var width, height, rules, map, tasks, links, nodes, svg, tick, radius, force, link, node;
        width = 960;
        height = 500;
        rules = [
            ['root', 'iot'],
            ['root', 'points'],
            ['root', 'camnative'],
            ['root', 'classifier'],
            ['points', 'classifier2'],
            ['camnative', 'classifier3'],
            ['classifier', 'consec'],
            ['iot', 'classifier1'],
            ['cloudclassif', 'schedule'],
            ['schedule', 'privacy'],
            ['privacy', 'roi'],
            ['roi', 'flooding'],

            ['classifier1', 'cloudclassif'],
            ['classifier2', 'cloudclassif'],
            ['classifier3', 'cloudclassif'],
            ['consec', 'cloudclassif']
        ];
        map = d3.map();
        rules.forEach(function(rule) {
            map.set(rule[0], {
                fixed: false
            });
            return map.set(rule[1], false);
        });
        map.set('root', {
            fixed: true,
            x: 100,
            y: height / 2
        });
        // map.set('P4', {
        //     fixed: true,
        //     x: width / 2 - 100,
        //     y: height / 2
        // });
        tasks = map.keys();
        links = rules.map(function(rule) {
            return {
                source: tasks.indexOf(rule[0]),
                target: tasks.indexOf(rule[1])
            };
        });
        nodes = tasks.map(function(k) {
            var entry;
            entry = {
                name: k
            };
            if (map.get(k).fixed) {
                entry.fixed = true;
                entry.x = map.get(k).x;
                entry.y = map.get(k).y;
            }
            return entry;
        });
        svg = d3.select("#chart")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);
        svg.append("svg:defs")
            .append("svg:marker")
            .attr("id", "arrow")
            .attr("viewBox", "0 0 10 10")
            .attr("refX", 0)
            .attr("refY", 5)
            .attr("markerUnits", "strokeWidth")
            .attr("markerWidth", 8)
            .attr("markerHeight", 6)
            // .attr("orient", "auto")
            .append("svg:path")
            .attr("d", "M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10 z");
        svg.append("line")
            .attr("x1", 5)
            .attr("x2", 50)
            .attr("y1", 5)
            .attr("y2", 50)
            .style("stroke", "black")
            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
            .attr("marker-end", "url(#arrow)");
        tick = function() {
            var arrowheadLength = 8, // from markerWidth
                nodeRadius = 10;
            link.each(function(d) {
                var x1 = d.source.x,
                    y1 = d.source.y,
                    x2 = d.target.x,
                    y2 = d.target.y,
                    angle = Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1);
                d.targetX = x2 - Math.cos(angle) * (nodeRadius + arrowheadLength);
                d.targetY = y2 - Math.sin(angle) * (nodeRadius + arrowheadLength);
            });
            link.selectAll("line").attr("x1", function(d) {
                return d.source.x;
            }).attr("y1", function(d) {
                return d.source.y;
            }).attr("x2", function(d) {
                return d.targetX;
            }).attr("y2", function(d) {
                return d.targetY;
            }).attr("marker-end", "url(#arrow)");
            node.attr("transform", function(d) {
                return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
            });
        };
        radius = d3.scale.sqrt().range([0, 6]);
        force = d3.layout.force().size([width / 2, height]).charge(-900).linkDistance(function(d) {
            return 40;
        });
        force.nodes(nodes).links(links).on("tick", tick).start();
        link = svg.selectAll(".link").data(links).enter().append("g").attr("class", "link");
        link.append("line").style("stroke-width", 1).attr("marker-end", "url(#arrow)");

        node = svg.selectAll(".node")
            .data(nodes)
            .enter()
            .append("g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .call(force.drag);
        node.append("rect")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("width", 100)
            .attr("height", 50);


        node.append("input")
            .attr("type", "checkbox")
            .attr("class", "mycheck")
            .attr("fill", "black");

        node.append("text")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return (d) - 3; })
            .attr("y", 50 / 2)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

        console.log("HERE2");
        console.log("HERE5");
    }).call(this);
```

I checked [D3 v3 appending checkbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263476/d3-v3-appending-checkbox), but that solution does not work.

Update

Added

```
node.append("foreignObject")
            .attr("width", 100)
            .attr("height", 100)
            .append("xhtml:chart")
            .append("div")
            .append("input")
            .attr("type", "checkbox");
```

Add the checkboxes are added to the node.

Comment: SVG does not allow HTML elements except as children of foreignObject elements.

Comment: Any suggestions on how I could accomplish that?

Comment: add a foreignObject element and add the input as a child of that element.

Comment: Added the foreignobject as the child and it works. Any ideas on how I could make it directed like the image above?

Answer (score 0):

I played around with this and got a bit further. I found discovered a few things:

1. As mentioned by others, put the checkbox inside of a <foreignObject>
2. Use the "xhtml:" prefix before the html objects inside of the foreignObject.
3. You have some bad math in your data functions. For example: **return (d) - 3;** returns NaN. You need something like **return d.x - 3;**
4. Items inside of the <g> element are positioned *relative* to the group. In my fiddle example (link at bottom), I positioned the top-lefts of the rectangles at (0,-16).

```js
// Create the <foreignObject>:
let ddiv = node.append("foreignObject") 
    .attr("x", -10) 
    .attr("y", -34) 
    .attr("width", 50)
    .attr("height",50)         
   .append("xhtml:div") // <<<---- xhtml: prefix!
     .classed("roundedOne", true)

ddiv.append("xhtml:input")  // <<<---- xhtml: prefix!
 .attr("type", "checkbox")
 .attr("id", (d) => d.name);
  
ddiv.append("xhtml:label") // <<<---- xhtml: prefix!
 .attr("for", (d) => d.name);
```

Check out my jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/visioguy/yz5tfgjm/

I added some fancy checkbox styling that fit better into your boxes, which is why I added the extra <div> and <label> to your code. You'll have to fiddle with more of the margins and sizes and offsets, and perhaps some of the force-layout parameters to get the layout to work properly.

[image: Fancy checkboxes inside of SVG groups]